# Vuetify 2.6.12 - Problem with v-data-table inside v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my application, when inserting a v-data-table inside a v-dialog, it is losing part of its CSS style.
Looking at the HTML, the class "v-application" and "v-application--is-ltr" are not being applied to v-dialog.
I need the same classes that are applied to all components inside  ("v-application" and "v-application--is-ltr"), inside . Without these classes the  is without application of some CSS. I imagine that even inside a v-dialog I could use a v-data-table and it would work
I've done several tests, like adding a v-row before the v-dialog, adding a v-container, putting v-col, removing v-col.
A lot of tests and I couldn't find a solution.
Has anyone gone through this problem?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Can you explain why you expect those classes to exist on v-dialog?  Those classes by default only exist on the root div with `id=app`.  Please add code snippets showing how your dialog component is structured within your app as well as any related code to better explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: why is there a vuetifyjs3 tag?

Comment: If you need specific CSS classes applied to your dialogs - you can use the `content-class` prop of `v-dialog`.

Comment: @yoduh I need the same classes that are applied to all components inside <v-app> ("v-application" and "v-application--is-ltr"), inside <v-dialog>. Without these classes the <v-data-table> is without application of some CSS. I imagine that even inside a v-dialog I could use a v-data-table and it would work

Comment: @IVOGELOV
I believe I wouldn't need to add a class that is already automatically added by <v-app>. The only thing I could see is that inside a <v-dialog> the classes I mentioned above are not applied.

Comment: The `v-application` class is automatically applied only on `v-app` - but not on any other component. On dialog contents the automatically applied CSS classes are `v-dialog` and `v-dialog--active` (plus some others, depending on the dialog props).

Comment: @IVOGELOV And that's exactly the problem. Due to the lack of classes applied by <v-app>, the css of the v-data-table is wrong: shadows are missing, the buttons are misaligned, a mess, and honestly the Vuetify documentation doesn't say anything about there being PECULIARITIES regarding use from v-dialog

Comment: Can you add CSS code snippets to your question showing what CSS you're trying to apply and what you're targeting?  Still not very clear what you're doing.  When you said "I need the same classes that are applied to all components inside <v-app> inside <v-dialog>".  How are you applying the same classnames to ALL components?  `v-application` and `v-application--is-ltr` **by default** only applies to the root element.  If you're doing something outside the default to somehow apply those classes to all child components, can you show how you're doing that?  Maybe a codesandbox if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Tables inside dialogs work just fine in Vuetify:

```js
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        template: '#main',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data:
{
      dlgVisible: false,
      header:
      [
        {
        value: 'fname',
        text: 'First Name'          ,
        class: 'font-weight-bold text-subtitle-1',
        },
        {
        value: 'lname',
        text: 'Last Name'         ,
        class: 'font-weight-bold text-subtitle-1',
        },
        {
        value: 'salary',
        text: 'Salary'          ,
        class: 'font-weight-bold text-subtitle-1',
        },
      ],
      rows:
      [
        {
          fname: 'John',
          lname: 'Doe',
          salary: 1000
        },
        {
          fname: 'John',
          lname: 'Doe',
          salary: 1000
        },
        {
          fname: 'John',
          lname: 'Doe',
          salary: 1000
        },
      ],
},
});
```

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
</div>

<template id="main">
  <v-app>
    <v-btn color="primary" @click="dlgVisible = true">Show dialog</v-btn>
    <v-dialog v-model="dlgVisible">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="primary white--text py-2">Dialog</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
      <v-data-table :items="rows" :headers="header">
       </v-data-table>
       </v-card-text>
       <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
         <v-btn color="primary" @click="dlgVisible = false">Close</v-btn>
         </v-card-actions>
         </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</template>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```